# Difference between Hpi.kfe, Hpi and Hscv in R's 'ks' package?

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing

There are three *bandwidth selector functions* programmed in the *ks* package: Hpi, Hscv and Hpi.kfe, what is the difference between them?

And what is the difference between a *plug-in* and a *smoothed cross validation* bandwidth selector?

Comment: Regarding your first question, the [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/ks.pdf) for this package indicates the differences between these commands and the corresponding references. I have used this package but I do not recall the Hpi.kfe bandwidth selector. In the [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v21/i07/paper) you can find the answer to your second question.

Comment: Well, the JSS paper does mention both selectors but doesn't say much about what makes them different from each other in plain english; that's really what I was looking for. The manual doesn't mention Hpi.kfe (used by the kde.test function) which is the one I'm most interested in.